# Cannot connect the virtual device sata0:1 because no corresponding device is available on the host

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-player

> Cannot connect the virtual device sata0:1 because no corresponding device is available on the host.

The error pops up when I enable the host/guest share and map the drive. I have installed the VMware Tools, etc.

[I tried to delete and then add back the the sata drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417796/unable-to-connect-to-the-internet) to VM Player, but it did not help.

I am using VM Player 12.5.5 on Win10 Pro Host, and Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

Well, I just uncheck to connect automatically,from VM settings, then I switch from 'Use pshysical drive' to ISO path. after reboot I didn't seen the error

Or, just remove cv/dvd drive from the serting of the machine

Comment: I just removed cd/dvd with Remove Button, and it worked

Answer (score 8):

I don't really know what is the cause of the issue. I do not have a CD/DVD drive on my host at all, so I don't know what SATA drive it is trying to connect, and why.

However, the error gives me an option of

> Don't try connect next time

And, by selecting *yes*, the error goes away next time. Also, I removed the CD/DVD drive form the configuration.

Also my share folder host/guest was always working fine.

Comment: Same about my host not having a CD/DVD drive. I went into the Virtual Machine Settings, selected the "CD/DVD (SATA)" item in the Hardware list and then unchecked the "Connect at power on" option. Haven't had the message since.

Comment: hi from 2020, HIT NO!!!! the prompt changed and now reads "do you want to connect this device every time"

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by following these steps

1. Shut down the virtual machine
2. Go to the top menu of the VMWare Fusion hypervisor

   1. In the submenu "Virtual Machine", choose "Settings", then, under "Removable Devices", choose "CD/DVD (SATA)"
3. Choose the downloaded ISO image (the ISO that you downloaded that contains the OS) from the dropdown menu
4. Click "Connect CD/DVD Drive"
5. Restart the virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

if you use Hard Disk (SATA)
You must Remover DVD/CD

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, this is not a satisfactory answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well. I think..

1. Check if you setup "fstab" for mount /dev/sr0(ex. CD-ROM ..)
2. If you setup that.. 
   A. Just check.."connected"... In "Virtual Machine Settings"
   B. Reboot you VM

All Done.